# How to resolve "too much recursion " in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, upload, jasny-bootstrap

I am trying to upload a video via jQuery ajax using **jasny fileinput.js**. When I trying to submit a form **too much recursion** in jQuery file. But if I removed the **jasny fileinput.js**, none of the error is occured.I dont' know what is cause of this issue. Please any help me to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: You should add some code if you want help :-)

Comment: Add the code you are using and the errors.

Comment: @ArunDNambissan I am getting error like "too much recursion

....support={},f=gb.isXML=function(a){var b=a&&(a.ownerDocument||a).documentElement..." in jquery.min.js (line 2, col 8136)